# SenderReceiverInterface with multiple data elements difference from multiple ports and each with single data element

Tags: autosar

In AUTOSAR, SenderReceiverInterface can have multiple data elements as shown below snippet.
Is there any advantage or implementation difference when multiple data elements are used in a single software port compared to multiple software ports and each having single data elemment in the respective SenderReceiverInterface?
Does all data elements of a single SenderReceiverInterface on a Software Port are received or transmitted in atomic way all together by RTE?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The collection of `dataElement`s in a `SenderReceiverInterface` is mostly a logistical choice. Designing `SenderReciverInterface`s with few or only one `dataElement` may increase the chance of being able to re-use the `SenderReceiverInterface` in other contexts. But there's also motivation to create more complex `SenderReceiverInterface`s because this saves time and takes away complexity for creating connectors between `PortPrototype`s.

The `dataElement`s are sent/received entirely separate from each other. If you want atomicity, there is always the choice to create `dataElement`s of composite data types. The elements of sich a composite data type are always send and received atomically.

Comment: So I understand now that for atomic read/write with SWC using RTE will require COMPOSITE Datatype which indirectly enforces use of ISignalGroup in COM Layer I suppose.
Question is, does using ISignalGroup and not associating with COMPOSITE Datatype also will make the SWC to RTE communication ATOMIC even though a set of Primitive Datatype are used within ISignalGroup via respective ISignals?

Comment: Such a configuration does not take much sense because the individual dataElements would not necessarily have coherent values to be sent in a signal group. What would be the benefit of such a configuration?